# Automating the sonarqube analysis trigger

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I am using sonarqube 6.7 , developer’s version and I run analysis through sonar scanner msbuild from my local machine . Is there any way to :
1) Trigger this analysis automatically on code check-in, without using sonar scanner ?
2) Can I get analysis report in mail ?
What do I have to do for each of these ?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually this kind of task is handled by CI tools like TeamCity, Jenkins, Gitlab runner etc. Every commit/push can trigger you analysis.
2. You can subscribe to notifications in SonarQube UI. Click **My Account** in top left corner, then **Notifications**. You can subscribe to all notification or per project.

Comment: Hi Peska , Can i trigger analysis while using VSTS(Azure Devops) as CI tool. Currently we are using VSTS as CI tool, can I achieve this with vsts.

Comment: Most likely yes, but since I'm not using vsts, I can give you only those links: 

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/sonarqube-integration-with-vsts/